# Accessing similarly named tf.Variable objects outside of their name_scope

Tags: tensorflow

I'm referring to the following piece (`convolution-relu-maxpool`) from a Tensorflow graph (full code [here](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/text_cnn.py)) for [text classification using CNN](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/):

```
    ...
    pooled_outputs = []
    for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_sizes):
        with tf.name_scope("conv-maxpool-%s" % filter_size):
            # Convolution Layer
            filter_shape = [filter_size, embedding_size, 1, num_filters]
            W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_filters]), name="b")
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                self.embedded_chars_expanded,
                W,
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding="VALID",
                name="conv")
            # Apply nonlinearity
            h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu")
            # Maxpooling over the outputs
            pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                h,
                ksize=[1, sequence_length - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding='VALID',
                name="pool")
                pooled_outputs.append(pooled)
    ...
```

**(UPDATED)**

Now, consider the following sample code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    shape = [1, 1, 1, 1]

    for idx in [1, 2]:
        with tf.name_scope("test%s" % idx):
            W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
```

How can I access each of these weight variables/objects, all using the identifier `W`, outside of their respective `name_scope` (which I require for performing a manual update). Or is there an alternate way to share these objects without losing the scoping?

I tried to use share variables with `variable_scope` as follows:

```
shape = [1, 1, 1, 1]
for idx in [1, 2]:
    with tf.name_scope("test%s" % idx):
        with tf.variable_scope("in_scope%s" % idx, reuse=None):
            W = tf.get_variable("W%s" % idx, shape, dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
```

However, printing `W.name` within `with tf.variable_scope("in_scope1", reuse=True)` returns `in_scope2/W2:0` and not `in_scope1/W1:0` as expected and required.

I'm not sure I understand what's going on here. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: not sure where you printed `W.name`. and what kind of "manual update" you want to perform on these weights, and on all weights or just some special weights? Why you care so much about `variable_scope`? What do you mean "without losing the scoping"?

Comment: @Seven the "manual update" is a sort of custom regularization method I'm working on. It has to be applied to a certain subset of weights in the entire graph. The thing is, since all weight variables/objects are identified by `W`, it is a real problem to access and share them with the said method. "Without losing scoping" simply means, while keeping each `W`'s respective scopes in consideration.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you. Outside of `name_scope`:

```
    for v in tf.trainable_variables():
        # print v.name

        if 'W' in v.name:
            # operate
```

Comment: It does the job, but is there a more effective (adhering to best practices) way of doing this?